# Audio trilateration algorithm using Python, how to estimate distance from decibel loudness

Tags: python, math, audio, raspberry-pi, pyaudio

I'm trying to develop an algorithm in Python, that uses calculates the position of a loud sound source given 3 microphones. One of the approaches I'm attempting is drawing 3 circles, with center at the known location of each microphone, and the radius the estimated distance from the audio loudness level (louder = closer, quieter = further). The intersection area will be the sound source.

Below is the code I'm using to compute loudness, coupled with `PyAudio` record. However, the loudness value is relative - while there is a difference in value for closer and further away microphones like -30 vs -15, it's not absolute and I can't use it to trilateration. I need to somehow convert the decibel values into the distance in meters. When I researched online, it says "For every doubling of distance, the sound level reduces by 6 decibels". But I'm not exactly sure how to implement that.

```py
def _loudness(chunk):
    '''Calculate and return volume of input samples
    Input chunk should be a numpy array of samples for analysis, as
    returned by sound card.  Sound card should be in 16-bit mono mode.
    Return value is measured in dB, will be from 0dB (maximum
    loudness) down to -80dB (no sound).  Typical very loud sound will
    be -1dB, typical silence is -36dB.
    '''
    data = np.array(chunk, dtype=float) / 32768.0
    ms = math.sqrt(np.sum(data ** 2.0) / len(data))
    if ms < 10e-8: ms = 10e-8
    return 10.0 * math.log(ms, 10.0)
```

Comment: This is a difficult problem that you can't solve in a single Python function. You'll need to calibrate each microphone separately. Start with one microphone and measure the relative change in amplitude when you move the object to different locations. When you start taking variance due to directionality into account you'll be on the right track.

Comment: @Woodford I just need a quick proof of concept right now. I don't have a precise enough microphone device for calibration. Can I use some precalibrated conversion scale for a perfectly empty room at standard temperature and pressure or something? Also if I were to measure the relative change, it's certainly not a linear relationship, more like a logarithmic/exponential relationship, which I'm unsure about.

Comment: Yes, it'll be very nonlinear and depend on more than just distance. Since the sound will be at any loudness that you don't know ahead of time you really need the difference in loudness between 2 microphones at a known distance apart to start making progress. Example: if A measures -20dB and B measures -14dB then the source *could* be twice as far away from A as it is from B.